# Create Python array.array Object from cStringIO Object

Tags: python, stringio

I want to create an `array.array` object from a `cStringIO` object:

```
    import cStringIO, array

    s = """
    <several lines of text>
    """

    f = cStringIO.StringIO(s)
    a = array.array('c')
    a.fromfile(f, len(s))
```

But I get the following exception:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "./myfile.py", line 22, in <module>  
>     a.fromfile(f, len(s))  
> TypeError: arg1 must be open file
> ```

It seems like `array.array()` is checking the `type()` of the first argument, which makes it incompatible with `cStringIO` (and `StringIO` for that matter).  Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a.fromstring()? Since the StringIO buffer is entirely in memory, there is no benefit to trying to use a file api to read the bits from one memory location to another.

```
a = array.array('c')
a.fromstring(s)
```

If you are using StringIO for another reason (as a memory buffer, or as a file earlier on), then you can use StringIO's getvalue() function to get the string value.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm parsing a file that's text interleaved with binary payloads, so in order to do this I had to use "a.fromstring(s[f.tell():bin_data_end])" and then move the StringIO forward with f.seek()